# Do we say "the bottom of the foot" and "the top of the foot" in general everyday conversations?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Do we say "**the bottom of the foot**" and "**the top of the foot**" in general everyday conversations as shown in the picture?

For example, "**the bottom of your foot is so dirty**". If we say "**your foot is dirty**", then it is not too accurate because only its bottom is dirty not the top one.

For "**hands**", we say "**palm**" and "**the back of the hand**". I don't know how to say the similar thing with "**feet**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part of your foot that you walk on is the *sole.*

In everyday speech we probably *would* say 'Your feet are dirty' without feeling it necessary to specify exactly which part. However, there is a formal word for the upper middle part of the foot - the [instep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instep).